# Cannot copy xlsx file with java

Tags: java, file, copy

I'm have that class for testing simple xlsx file copy

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("Classeur2.xlsx");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    printWriter.print(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Classeur1.xlsx"))));
    printWriter.close();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[150];
    System.out.println("++ Classeur1.xlsx ++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Classeur1.xlsx"))).substring(0,150));
    System.arraycopy(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Classeur1.xlsx")), 0, bytes, 0, 150);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
    System.out.println("++ Classeur2.xlsx ++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println(new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Classeur2.xlsx"))).substring(0,150));
    System.arraycopy(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Classeur2.xlsx")), 0, bytes, 0, 150);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
}
```

The `Classeur1.xlsx` file is opening normaly. The `Classeur2.xlsx` file is not opening (file is corrupted).

The output when running

```
++ Classeur1.xlsx ++++++++++++++++++++++
PK    ! b�h^  �  [Content_Types].xml �(�                                                                                               
[80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 98, -18, -99, 104, 94, 1, 0, 0, -112, 4, 0, 0, 19, 0, 8, 2, 91, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 95, 84, 121, 112, 101, 115, 93, 46, 120, 109, 108, 32, -94, 4, 2, 40, -96, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
++ Classeur2.xlsx ++++++++++++++++++++++
PK    ! b�h^  �  [Content_Types].xml �(�                                                                                               
[80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 98, -17, -65, -67, 104, 94, 1, 0, 0, -17, -65, -67, 4, 0, 0, 19, 0, 8, 2, 91, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 95, 84, 121, 112, 101, 115, 93, 46, 120, 109, 108, 32, -17, -65, -67, 4, 2, 40, -17, -65, -67, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

There seems to be a difference after the 15th byte.  Is it a problem of encoding ?
I don't know the source file encoding (it can have multiples origins and is send to me by email).  What's the solution ?

Comment: Don't use Writer classes to output arbitrary binary values. Use Outputstreams.

Comment: `Is it a problem of encoding?` Yes. `I don't know the source file encoding` It has no text encoding, its binary data. Don't treat it as text.

Comment: Don’t use Writers at all.  Don’t use Strings at all.  (Unlike C, in Java it is *never* correct to use Strings to hold bytes.)  Just use `Files.copy(Path.of("Classeur1.xlsx"), Path.of("Classeur2.xlsx"))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use InputStream to read data, then OutputStream to write data.
To transport the data from InputStream to OutputStream use a byte array.

Also, do not use functions like readAllBytes() if files can be bigger than your memory.

Code may look like this:

```
try(InputStream in = new FileInputStream(...); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(...)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read = in.read(buffer);
    while (read >=0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        read = in.read(buffer);
    }
}
```